# Automatic redeploy after fail

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm using VSTS to automatically release my app after each commit to the specific branch. The tasks are basically:

1. Recreate database
2. If 1st ok -> Deploy API and Web
3. If 2nd ok -> Deploy and restart some windows services

During the second step sometimes it happens that deploy fails because of some connection or IIS issue. This is not really
a big deal I do not want to be very specific about the error nature here. All I have to do when it happens is to go to the `VSTS` and click `Redeploy` on failed task.

But I was wondering if there is a way to automate that process. So in case of fail deployment and specific error I want to trigger
`Redeploy` automatically. Is there a way to do this in VSTS? Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have only one environment or multiple environments? Do you want to redeploy the failed task or the whole environment(s)?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT What I'm doing manually is I go to `VSTS` and click redeploy on the task (usually it is the second task that fails). Then `VSTS` will restart from second task once again and continue with task 3 after success. All I want to automate is just this redeploy click after fail.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT Ah and yes! Each task is on different `environment`. So basically what I meant by `task` was `environment`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have two options which can helps you redeploy the second task/environment.

#### Option 1: add the same tasks as the second task and execute the following tasks when previous task is failed

If you want to reploy three times, you can add the same three tasks as the second task in second environment. For the three tasks you add, set only w**hen a previous task has failed** for **Run this task** option. So it can redeploy the second task/environment not bigger than three times.

[image]

#### Option 2: add a PowerShell task after second task in second environment, if the second task failed, deploy the second environment again

In the PowerShell task, you should do below operations.

**1.Get the current release log by [rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#get-a-release):**

```
GET https://account.vsrm.visualstudio.com/Git2/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseID}
```

For the releaseID, you can get the value by predefined variable `$(Release.ReleaseId)`.

**2.Get second task status**

In the rest API response, you can check your second task by searching the task **display name** and get the `status` for the task. As below example, the task display name is `PowerShell Script`, and the task is failed (`status` value is `failed`).

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "timelineRecordId": "ae95a8be-6259-466d-ba8d-93711a922237",
    "name": "PowerShell Script",
    "dateStarted": "2017-10-03T02:43:25.757Z",
    "dateEnded": "2017-10-03T02:43:29.073Z",
    "startTime": "2017-10-03T02:43:25.757Z",
    "finishTime": "2017-10-03T02:43:29.073Z",
    "status": "failed",
    "rank": 4,
    "issues": [
       {
           "issueType": "Error",
           "message": "agit : The term 'agit' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check \r\nthe spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.\r\nAt D:\\a\\_temp\\0a858f5c-894b-4944-bed4-54b3cbed48bc.ps1:1 char:1\r\n+ agit\r\n+ ~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (agit:String) [], CommandNotFoundException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException\r\n \r\n"
       },
       {
           "issueType": "Error",
           "message": "Process completed with exit code 0 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream."
       }
    ],
   "task": {
      "id": "e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1",
      "name": "PowerShell",
      "version": "1.2.3"
   },
   "agentName": "Hosted Agent",
   "logUrl": "https://account.vsrm.visualstudio.com/f7855e29-6f8d-429d-8c9b-41fd4d7e70a4/_apis/Release/releases/300/environments/374/tasks/5/logs?releaseDeployPhaseId=344"
}
```

**3.If the second task is failed, then deploy the second environment again by [rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#update-release-environment):**

```
PATCH https://account.vsrm.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/Release/releases/{releaseID}/environments/{environmentID}?api-version=4.0-preview.4
```

For the environmentID, you can also get in by perdefined variable `$(Release.EnvironmentId)`.

Comment: Trying to deploy the second environment from within that same stage seems troublesome. VS402964: Transitioning of stage from state 'InProgress' to state 'InProgress' is not allowed.